# Kotlin - Map integers to lists of lists

Tags: android, kotlin

I am trying to find the proper syntax to initialize "Map<,<List<List>>>" in kotlin. I am a bit new to kotlin. I have variables initialized in my class as this:

```
var jitterMs: Double = 0.0
```

The way I am trying to initialize is this:

```
val bandMap: Map<Int,<List<List<String>>>> = emptyMap()
```

It gives me an error that a proper getter or setter is expected, and I think that's because it just doesn't understand what I am trying to do. What is wrong with this syntax?

Thanks,

Edit: As Tenfour pointed out, I actually want a mutable map. This is what I have now as an error saying there is a type error:

```
val bandMap: MutableMap<Int,List<List<String>>> = emptyMap()
```

Comment: You have an extra set of `<>` wrapped around your outer List. Also, since this is a `val`, you won't be able to do much with a read-only Map instead of a MutableMap.

Comment: Thank you, no more syntax errors. I want a MutableMap, so I then changed that, thanks. I am getting an error for emptymap() now with that:                                                             
                                                                                                                                        val bandMap: MutableMap<Int,List<List<String>>> = emptyMap()

Comment: You need to use `mutableMapOf()` instead of `emptyMap()`. `emptyMap` returns a read-only Map.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how you would do it:

```
val bandMap: Map<Int, List<List<String>>> = emptyMap()
```

For a `MutableMap` write the following:

```
val bandMap: MutableMap<Int, List<List<String>>> = mutableMapOf()
```

Or, for the most idiomatic way to make a `mutableMap` would be:

```
val bandMap = mutableMapOf<Int, List<List<String>>>()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
val bandMap: Map<Int,List<List<String>>> = emptyMap()
```

This will work. You added extra < >